# How to click a GridView Row to populate an updatepanel with data from the row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a GridView that gets its data from a LINQ-query using entity framework. Now I want to be able to click a row to fill an updatepanel, sitting next to the gridview, with properties from the object on the clicked row.

Now this is what I've got so far:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Payment" HeaderText="Payment" SortExpression="Payment" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Creator" HeaderText="Creator" SortExpression="Creator" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobId" HeaderText="JobId" SortExpression="JobId" />
                    </Columns>
[...]
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="ProfileTop">
                                <asp:Label ID="JobTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="JobDescription" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="JobCreator" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now the code behind looks as following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int theJobId = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "JobId");
        Session["JobToShow"] = theJobId;

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick",
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));

        e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int c = (int)Session["JobToShow"];
    var currentJob = JobDataFactory.RetrieveJob(c);

    JobTitle.Text = currentJob.Title;
    JobDescription.Text = currentJob.Descripton;
}
```

I've tried a couple of different approaches but with no luck. I can click a gridview row, and trigger the updatepanel to update with new data. But sadly it's not the properties from the clicked row, it's from the latest created row. So my problem is how I catch what row has been clicked, so I can use that to update the updatepanel with correct information.

**EDIT:**

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text); 
    var currentJob = JobDataFactory.RetrieveJob(c);
```

This code from speti43 did the trick, just had to do convert instead of cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't need to store this in Session.

You can use [GridViewSelectEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewselecteventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for [SelectedIndexChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    var row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    int c = (int)row.Cells[x].Text ; //x is the number of appropriate column 
    var currentJob = JobDataFactory.RetrieveJob(c);
```

or

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
    int c = (int)row.Cells[x].Text ; //x is the number of appropriate column 
    var currentJob = JobDataFactory.RetrieveJob(c);
```

Comment: This wouldn't require a page refresh and then clear out the gridview?

Comment: Why would? Updatepanel does the partial refresh. I don't think that needs to clear out the gridview.